# Mockito Expect an Exception

Tags: exception, mockito, junit4, expect, mockmvc

I'm trying to test the method below with Mockito and Junit:

```java
@Transactional
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT,value ="/updateEmployer/{empId}")
public @ResponseBody Object updateEmployer(@PathVariable Integer empId,) throws Exception {

    Employee e = EmployeeRepository.findOne(empId);

    for (Department de : e.getDepartement()){
        de.setDepartmentName(e.getName + "_" + de.getName());       
    }
    EmployeeRepository..saveAndFlush(e);
    return null;
}
```

This is the method Test:

```java
@Test  // throw java.lang.NullPointerException
 public void updateEmployeeFailureTest() throws Exception {

        mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders
                    .put("/updateEmployer/{empId}",18)                      
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andDo(print())         

              .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.view().name("errorPage"))
               .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().attributeExists("exception"))
              .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/jsp/errorPage.jsp"))
              .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isInternalServerError());       

    }
```

The printstack:

```java
 MockHttpServletRequest:
     HTTP Method = PUT
     Request URI = /updateEmployer/18
      Parameters = {}
         Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json], Accept=   application/json]}

         Handler:
            Type = com.controllers.employeeController
          Method = public java.lang.Object    com.controllers.employeeController.updateEmployer(java.lang.Integer) throws   java.lang.Exception

           Async:
      Was async started = false
      Async result = null

    Resolved Exception:
            ***Type = java.lang.NullPointerException***

    ModelAndView:
       View name = errorPage
            View = null
       Attribute = exception
           ***value = java.lang.NullPointerException***

         FlashMap:

  MockHttpServletResponse:
          Status = 500
   Error message = null
         Headers = {}
    Content type = null
            Body = 
   Forwarded URL = /WEB-INF/jsp/errorPage.jsp
  Redirected URL = null
         Cookies = []
```

It's work but when i try to catch the text or the exception throwed  by this method
adding  @Test (expected= java.lang.NullPointerException.class)  i have this error:

***java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: java.lang.NullPointerException***

when i try to get the nullPointerException Text as a value of the attribute (exception) of the section  ModelAndView i get this error:

***java.lang.AssertionError: Model attribute 'exception' expected:java.lang.NullPointerException but  was:java.lang.NullPointerException***

Is there a way to expect the exception throwed or the text in the value attribut ( value = java.lang.NullPointerException) or the Text in the Resolved Exception section using mockito (mockmvc)?

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: *when i try to get the nullPointerException Text as a value of the attribute (exception)*: how do you do that? Show us the code.

Comment: Adding an expectation like this:.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().attribute("exception","java.lang.NullPointerException"));

Comment: Spring doesn't store the String "java.lang.N‌​ullPointerException", as your test expects, in the exception attribute. It stores the *instance* of NullPointerException.

Comment: I tried with this:  .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().attribute("exception", java.lang.NullPointerException.class))  and i get this error :  java.lang.AssertionError: Model attribute 'exception' expected:<class java.lang.NullPointerException> but was:<java.lang.NullPointerException>  . Tried also passing a new instane of NPE (Same assertion error) .So, what expectation should i write th have this instance? i want to have a the instance or the text , but i don't have any idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test that the `exception` attribute of the model is an instance of NullPointerException.

This can be done using a Hamcrest matcher:

```
 .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().attribute(
     "exception", 
      Matchers.isA(NullPointerException.class))
```

Comment: Thank you, but now i got this error:  java.lang.AssertionError: Model attribute 'exception' expected:<null> but was:<java.lang.NullPointerException>. I saw in javaDoc tha IsA method returns always null. Any others idee.

Comment: The Matchers class to use is the one from hamcrest, not from Mockito: http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/index.html?org/hamcrest/Matchers.html

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution would be to catch the `exception` through the `MvcResult`, like this:

```
...
MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(...)
        ...
        ...
        .andReturn();

assertThat(result.getResolvedException(), instanceOf(YourException.class));
assertThat(result.getResolvedException().getMessage(), is("Your exception message");
...
```